# Select most early coming employees

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following problem:

> select most early coming   employees for  every location    city,show  location city and  coming date

I have tried following  one

```
select  e.hiredate  as LOC,d.loc  as COMDATE
from    emp e, dept  d
where   e.hiredate in (
    select  min(e.hiredate) 
    from  emp e
    group by d.loc
)
```

it  shows  following result

```
17-DEC-80   NEW YORK
17-DEC-80   DALLAS
17-DEC-80   CHICAGO
17-DEC-80   BOSTON
```

but problem is that there is only one 17-DEC-80,so it means that it repeats itself, how could I fix it?

Comment: You need to provide your table structure before you can get a full answer.

Comment: `group by d.loc` is totally unneeded. its effect would be the same without the group by (and consequentially = instead of in would be the same) as "d" doesn't exist within the sub query. if you meant for a date PER `loc` then that would need a diff solution. I note the answer you accepted had the same group by oddity. in that case, you really just wanted the earliest employee regardless of department? if you wanted per department, the only answer that gave that was DazzaL's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a cross join or Cartesian product in your query as not joining emp and dept tables. Simpler version of first query by JW. And aliases are not correct...:

```
select  e.hiredate  as LOC,d.loc  as COMDATE
 from    scott.emp e, scott.dept  d
 where e.deptno= d.deptno -- Cartesian if you not join --
 and e.hiredate in (
     select  min(e.hiredate) 
      from  scott.emp e
      group by d.loc
   )
  /
```

Answer (score 1):

the result is a product from `cross join`, you need to supply the relationship between the tables. ex

```
SELECT  e.hiredate AS LOC,
        d.loc AS COMDATE
FROM    emp e
        INNER JOIN dept d 
            ON e.deptno = d.deptno
WHERE   e.hiredate IN 
        (
            SELECT min(e.hiredate)
            FROM emp e
            GROUP BY d.loc
        )
```

Comment: @dato it's the name of column that defines the relationship of the two tables (*or how are they connected*).

Comment: there  is deptno for   connection

Comment: so it should be `ON e.deptno = d.deptno`

Answer (score 1):

if you need to select other fields along with the hiredate/location you can use the `rank()` analytic:

```
select *
  from (select e.*, d.loc, rank() over (partition by d.loc order by e.hiredate) rnk
          from emp e
               inner join dept d
                       on d.deptno = e.deptno
       )
 where rnk = 1;
```

if you only needed hiredate and location then just use `min()`

```
select min(e.hiredate), d.loc
  from emp e
       inner join dept d
               on d.deptno = e.deptno
 group by d.loc;
```